# Frustrated with "pyOpenSSL" module not be acknowledged

Tags: python, importerror, pyopenssl

Environment: OS X BigSur 11.2.2; MacBook Pro Intel

I am attempting to get pyOpenSSL to work in a Python3 environment.  I have been working on converting from using Py2 to Py3.  I could easily make this work in Python2; but I really need to get off Python2 for obvious reasons.

In my python script, I simply have the command of:  "import pyOpenSSL".   I have also tried just "import OpenSSL" and "import cryptography", all also produce similar "No module named..." errors. No matter the syntax, spelling, or case, nothing works.

During all the attempts below, installation is a success; and I verified with "pip3 list".

I have tried:

- installing directly into the system Python - no go.
- installed pyenv and installed Python 3.8.7 and used pip3 to install pyOpenSSL - no go.
- installed virtualenvwrapper and created a virtual environment, installed there, still no go.

I even verified while in python, that the module was installed using the following:

```
import pkg_resources
installed_packages = pkg_resources.working_set
installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
   for i in installed_packages])
print(installed_packages_list)
['appdirs==1.4.4', 'cffi==1.14.5', 'cryptography==3.4.6', 'distlib==0.3.1', 'filelock==3.0.12', 'pbr==5.5.1', 'pip==21.0.1', 'pycparser==2.20', 'pyopenssl==19.1.0', 'setuptools==49.2.1', 'six==1.15.0', 'stevedore==3.3.0', 'virtualenv-clone==0.5.4', 'virtualenv==20.4.2', 'virtualenvwrapper==4.8.4']
```

Even using non-pip, shows at least "openSSL" installed.

```
>>> help("modules")

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

/Users/jewettg/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/distutils_patch.py:25: UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged and may exhibit undesirable behaviors or errors. Please use Setuptools' objects directly or at least import Setuptools first.
  warnings.warn(
OpenSSL             _thread             functools           resource
__future__          _threading_local    gc                  rlcompleter
_abc                _tkinter            genericpath         runpy
_ast                _tracemalloc        getopt              sched
_asyncio            _uuid               getpass             secrets
_bisect             _warnings           gettext             select
_blake2             _weakref            glob                selectors
_bootlocale         _weakrefset         grp                 setuptools
_bz2                _xxsubinterpreters  gzip                shelve
_cffi_backend       _xxtestfuzz         hashlib             shlex
_codecs             abc                 heapq               shutil
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong!  HELP!?

Comment: Also note; that I have tried older versions of PyOpenSSL (19.1.10) and the absolute latest (20.0.1).

Comment: Where are you getting these errors, when trying to run your code snippet? If you're using `python3 xxx.py` to run your programs, I suggest installing modules using `python3 -m pip install packagename`, to make sure the modules are installed for whichever version of python you're actively using.

Comment: Thank you @JasonRebeloNeves - I have done just that.  I also have a local alias that points python to python3.  So it is being installed in python3 environment.

Comment: What is the _exact_ error you get on import? Can you paste it here? If not, can you at least name the modules that it's not finding?

Comment: @MattMessersmith
My apologies, it is the pyOpenSSL module.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./f5_cert_create.py", line 96, in <module>
    import OpenSSL
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenSSL'

As mentioned above, I have tried different names and they all produce the same result, even while verifying the named module in the error is present.

Comment: @MattMessersmith:  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenSSL';  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyOpenSSL'; ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyopenssl'; ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you about pyenv or other managers, but `conda` rarely lets me down. I've verified I can install this lib from a clean `conda` env w/ python3.8 and import it:

```
(base) $ conda create python=3.8 -n pyssl
...
(base) $ conda activate pyssl
(pyssl) $ pip install pyopenssl
...
Successfully installed cffi-1.14.5 cryptography-3.4.6 pycparser-2.20 pyopenssl-20.0.1 six-1.15.0
(pyssl) $ python
Python 3.8.8 (default, Feb 24 2021, 21:46:12)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import OpenSSL
>>>
```

So you'll almost certainly want to do `import OpenSSL`. I'm on Windows, but using WSL2. None of that should matter, though.

Usually when these issues occur, it's because you've installed the library to one Python interpreter but are accidentally invoking a *different* interpreter (where you did not install the lib) when you actually run.

Comment: I am trying Conda now; will update/post my experience, and let you know.  pyenv is not available on RHEL; where I am trying this now.    So all my original issues were on OS X; so I am trying to replicate on RHEL.

Comment: I am just baffled.  I can not get it to work with openSSL.  I can get it to work with mysql.connector, requests, etc.. those all work.   I created the conda environment, activated it, verified that pyopenssl was not installed, installed it, and still no go.

I then verified that for giggles mysql.connector and requests are installed and the code would not work without them installed, but installed, the code worked, allowed the import.

Comment: The formatting stinks, but to replicate what you did above:   I did a "pip list", and verified that "pyOpenSSL       20.0.1" was installed.   I then launched python, "Python 3.6.13 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Feb 23 2021, 21:15:04) [GCC 7.3.0] on linux".  I then proceeded to "import openssl" and "import pyopenssl" and "Traceback (most recent call last):  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openssl'
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyopenssl'"

Comment: @jewettg just as a note the case matters, would need to do `import OpenSSL`

Comment: @jewettg And if you created the conda env as i did above, you're invoking the wrong interpreter. Did you do `python=3.6` instead of `python=3.8`?

Comment: OK, so apparently case matters, and you can not rely on module name to match what you use for import.  ?!?!   If you "pip install pyopenssl", you have to "import OpenSSL" (case sensitive).  How do you figure this stuff out?  How confusing.

FYI:  It worked in Python 3.6 and 3.8; so long as I paid attention to case sensitivity!

Comment: @jewettg figured it out by reading the docs. I will grant you that what they're doing isn't PEP8 compliant, and going against the norm causes this type of confusion. That said, I would assume the module is very old and probably a python2 port. Maybe we can give them some slack ;). It is free, after all.